# Equation for 3D vector rotation

Tags: matrices, vectors, 3d, rotations

Suppose I have a vector $P_0$ in a direct orthonormed system and a rotation of this vector defined by a rotation matrix $RM$.

Which of the two following equations is correct to find the new coordinates of the vector $P_0$ rotated onto  a new vector $P_1$ ?

$$
\vec{\mathbf P}_1
\begin{bmatrix} \vec x_1 \\ \vec y_1 \\ \vec z_1 \end{bmatrix}
= RM \times
\vec{\mathbf P}_0 \begin{bmatrix} \vec x_0 \\ \vec y_0 \\ \vec z_0 \end{bmatrix} \tag1
$$
or
$$
\vec{\mathbf P}_0
\begin{bmatrix} \vec x_1 \\ \vec y_1 \\ \vec z_1 \end{bmatrix}
= RM \times
\vec{\mathbf P}_1 \begin{bmatrix} \vec x_0 \\ \vec y_0 \\ \vec z_0 \end{bmatrix}
\quad \rightarrow \quad
\vec{\mathbf P}_1
\begin{bmatrix} \vec x_1 \\ \vec y_1 \\ \vec z_1 \end{bmatrix}
= RM^{-1} \times
\vec{\mathbf P}_0 \begin{bmatrix} \vec x_0 \\ \vec y_0 \\ \vec z_0 \end{bmatrix} \tag2
$$
([Original image of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmGDC.png))

I have heard both of them from different sources and I am now confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your confusion is between an [active and  a passive transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation).

To say that $R_M$ is the matrix that rotates a vector $P_0$ to a vector $P_1$ means that if we  represent $P_0$ in the standard basis, than $P_1=R_M P_0$ is the rotated vector in the same standard basis. And this is an **active** rotation.

The inverse matrix $R_M^{-1}$ represents the inverse rotation in the standard basis, i.e. the rotation such that $P_0=R_M^{-1}P_1$.

This inverse matrix can be used to find the components of the starting vector $P_0$ in a new basis basis $B$ that is rotated by $R_M$ with respect to the standard basis, in the sense that the components of $P_0$ in this basis $B$ are given by $[P_0]_B=R_M^{-1}P_0$. And this is a **passive** rotation.

Comment: I don't quite get it. On [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes), a change of basis is described as  "new coordinates" = RM x "old coordinates"  that is to say in the same way as an active transformation or alibi.  Shouldn't it be a passive transformation formulated as "new coordinates" = RM-1 x "old coordinates" ?  What are the consequences on the results ?

Comment: It is a common confusion derived from notation. You  can see that  the matrix $ \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta&\sin \theta\\-\sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}$ is the inverse of the matrix that represents a rotation of a vector of angle $\theta$ ( in standard basis) so it is a passive rotation, that is it represents a vector in a rotated  reference system.

Comment: So this is more a transposed matrix as a inverted matrix ?  And the impact should only concern the direction of the rotation, not the values of the vector's components ?

Comment: Yes. the point is that $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2\theta=1$. So inverse and transpose are the same for such matrices.